# Should I consider using Hadoop for a new PHP application?

Tags: php, mysql, database, hadoop, internationalization

I've built a PHP web application prototype as a startup project with a MySQL database behind it, but now the whole thing needs to be rewritten.

I'd like to keep PHP as the server side language but I don't know what kind of database I should use to be able to search and fetch data constantly using mainly AJAX.

I think a MySQL relational database would do the job for a while, but I'd like to be prepared for the time when I have many users from all around the world who need to access their data quickly. Right now all I have got is a VPS at Digital Ocean that runs PHP and MySQL, it serves my 70 test users well.

But what if my numbers start to increase? I can't just store hundreds of million (or billions) rows of data in one single database without having latency etc. problems, can I? Should I consider using Hadoop from the very beginning so I won't have that much problem in the future? How should I get prepared for having to scale things in the future?

Comment: This sounds like premature optimisation to me. MySQL can cope with millions of rows just fine, given the right hardware, and probably billions too if you shard, cache and otherwise get your architecture right.

Comment: Also, the database you select should depend a lot on the type of data you are storing / querying.  Relational databases and NoSQL databases perform two different tasks and you should select the right tool for the job.

Comment: Think about it as a kind of social bookmarking application. Imagine that users can save as many links as they like, also some metadata get stored as well as the tags for the different url-s. There's a click statistics to every single link, a login statistics, a ranking system based on a link's popularity etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely go for Hadoop. Start with may be 5 nodes cluster and then scale up as required. Else, I would suggest go for [Amazon EMR](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticmapreduce/) you can always scale up and down as you need.

You can have HBase as a database on top of hadoop and use [HIVE](https://hive.apache.org/) which is sqlike language. This was initially developed by Facebook for internal purpose (exactly similar situation like you, they were unable to handle huge data and most of the code is in PHP and mysql). [HIVE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Hive) converts sqlike commands to map reduce and runs the job on the hadoop cluster.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you, i'll definetelly give Hadoop and HIVE a try. I don't have any experience with this Big Data technologies, but do you think it's possible (or a good idea) to store some of the data (like users, links, tags etc.) in a relational database, and store all the log data (click and login statistics etc) in Hadoop?